# Adding more elements to a sequence so that it have the desired probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

If I need to generate N numbers from a given probability distribution, I am aware of how to do this.

**But my problem is out of the N numbers, say, k numbers are already fixed. (k is very small than n).**

I am wondering what is the best way of generating the other elements so that the overall distribution is close to the given distribution?

EDIT:

I will give a clear example of my problem:

I have to select 100 numbers from a set of 1000 numbers. The selection is done independently and with replacement. {p1, p2,...., p1000} is the vector of probabilities representing the sampling probability (all values are non zero) for each of the 1000 elements.

Now, say, I already have k elements decided without following the sampling procedure. i.e., only 100-k is left to be selected.

How should I design my new sampling probabilities {q1, q2,...,q1000} so that in effect we get the original distribution {p1,p2,...p1000}, or closest to the original distribution If KL divergence is my measure.

Comment: Are you using a simple random sample or independent sampling?

Comment: independent sampling from the set with replacement.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in general, for example if all $k$ numbers are equal to $1000000000$ I don't think you can define the other elements to be close to a $N(0, 1)$ distribution, unless $k$ is completely negligible. But if $k$ is that negligible, just use the desired distribution to generate the other numbers.

Comment: Would you care to define *close*?

Comment: More obvious example, if all $k$ numbers are very large and your desired distribution is the degenerate distribution (say, guaranteed to be 0).

Comment: "close" hasn't got any apparent meaning.  My guess is that if you specify what measure you mean to take it will be obvious how to define the new point.

Comment: @Henry I will edit to make more sense.

Comment: @lulu I added details